# no matching function call to error in vector.push_back

Tags: c++, g++

I am getting the following error while compiling my C++ program:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<ChainingTable<int>::Record, std::allocator<ChainingTable<int>::Record> >::push_back(ChainingTable<int>::Record*)'
  324 |         vector_.push_back(new Record(key, value));
```

The error is coming from the line:

```cpp
template <class TYPE>
bool ChainingTable<TYPE>::update(const std::string &key, const TYPE &value)
{
    if (!keyExists)
        {
            vector_.push_back(new Record(key, value));
        }
}
```

This is defined for the class:

```
class ChainingTable : public Table<TYPE>
{
    struct Record
    {
        TYPE data_;
        std::string key_;
        Record(const std::string &key, const TYPE &data)
        {
            key_ = key;
            data_ = data;
        }
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<Record>> records_;
    int capacity_; // capacity of the array
```

Complete code:

```
int sz = numRecords();
bool rc = true;
std::hash<std::string> hashFunction;
size_t hash = hashFunction(key);
size_t idx = hash % capacity_;
std::vector<Record> vector_ = records_[idx];
bool keyExists = false;
for (int i = 0; i < vector_.size(); i++)
{
    if (vector_[i].key_ == key)
    {
        vector_[i].data_ = value;
        keyExists = true;
    }
}
if (!keyExists)
{
    vector_.push_back(new Record(key, value));
}
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You are trying to push a pointer (returned by `new`), but it looks like the vector is initialized to use objects.

Comment: What is the type variable `vector_`? I mean how did you defined it. Can you show us that.  There doesn't seem to be a definition of `vector_` in your above given snippets.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, I added the complete code. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector is declared to store objects of type `Record`, not pointers to them (`Record *`) but you are trying to push result of `operator new` which returns `Record *`, just use `std::vector::emplace_back` instead:

```
vector_.emplace_back(key, value);
```

Note: in this line

```
std::vector<Record> vector_ = records_[idx];
```

you create a copy and later modify it, seems that you need a reference.

Note2: in your search loop you do not terminate even if you find object already, you should add `break` into `if` statement, that will make it more effective.

Comment: I added complete code to avoid any confusion

Comment: @daniel that does not change anything, my answer still persists

Comment: Got it. But can I then do `Record *record = new Record(key, value);` and do vector_.push_back(*record)? Will that be ok?

Comment: @daniel that will compile, but you will create an unnecessary copy and make memory leak (unless you delete it afterwards, but still will make doing all that unnecessary)

Comment: emplace_back will automatically convert it to a record and push it into vector?

Comment: @daniel emplace_back will create `Record` in place and pass parameters to ctor directly. You may call `vector_.push_back(Record(key,value));` but that will create temporary and then pass it. Later case can be optimized, but still unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. I need one clarity. As I am declaring the vector-like - `std::vector<std::vector<Record>> records_`  So record_[0] is a vector but when I do .size() on it throws segmentation fault. Do I have to initialize the internal vector, and how do I do it?

Comment: @daniel you cannot have uninitialized vector as you cannot create it bypassing its ctor. Looks like you access `records_[0]` when `records_` itself is empty, which is UB and can easily lead to coredump when you access that element inside.

Comment: How do I initialize records_ with empty vector? I am a java programmer. C++ is giving me headaches. Similar things, but they behave differently like the new operator

Comment: @daniel yes it is quite obvious you have java background. You should take some time and learn difference in C++ btw value and pointer, unlike java they are different. As of vector - when default initialized it is empty, so you cannot use `[0]` on it (or any other index). Vector can change its size variuos ways - you can pass size to ctor on creation, you can call `std::vector::resize()` after a vector is created, you can call `push_back` or `emplace_back` which will add one element. By default on your `records_` if you resize or pass size to it's ctor it will create empty vectors inside.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that your variable `vector_`  holds objects of type `Record` but when you write:

```
vector_.push_back(new Record(key, value));
```

You are trying to add a pointer to a `Record` object in the vector `vector_` instead of adding the `Record` object itself.

You can **solve** it by writing:

```
vector_.emplace_back(key, value);
```

**Alternate solution**

Note that there is another possible solution which is to use:

```
vector_.push_back(Record(key, value));
```

But using `emplace_back` should be preferred.